# Heroku - '@heroku/buildpack-registry not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks'

Tags: node.js, heroku, nuxt.js

I am attempting to launch my Nuxt SSR/Universal app through Heroku, due to Netlify no longer meeting my needs (I need backend functionality). By following the tutorial [here](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment/), and then trying to deal with subsequent errors through use of [third-party buildpacks](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs), and I ended up at the following error:

`npm ERR! @heroku/buildpack-registry not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks`

full output for context:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.8
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! @heroku/buildpack-registry not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.dVBXd/_logs/2020-11-01T03_35_25_039Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

As near as I can tell, there isn't a `buildpack-registry` folder on my local copy of @heroku, so I don't know what that folder is supposed to have. I have the Heroku CLI for npm, and running `heroku buildpacks` gets me:

```
1. heroku/nodejs
2. https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildback-phantomjs.git
```

which should all be valid. I've tried deploying on a clean environment with the same result.

Sorry if the question is a bit rambly, I just have no idea where to start trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

It urns out I forgot to install some packages the `@heroku-cli` requires. Running the following install command fixed it for me, but you may be missing packages that I have, or I may be missing packages that you have.

```
npm i @heroku/buildpack-registry async-file cli-ux got phoenix
```

I was initially confused because there was no @heroku module, but it was only accessible as the @heroku/buildpack-registry