# Heroku/React Deployment - Random Dependancies are not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, heroku-cli

I'm trying to host my React App (with mongodb backend) through Heroku.

It's my first time running through Heroku and the ReactApp was built before Heroku was implemented. My end goal is for both the MongoDB Backend and the React Frontend to be hosted in one go.

The files are hosted to Heroku via GithubI followed the tutorials and got everything uploading, but I run into this error again and again:

```
npm ERR! (Insert Dependancy here)valid-url not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks
```

Most often it manifests as:

```
npm ERR! valid-url not accessible from u/heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks

npm ERR! @heroku/buildpack-registry not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks
```

I've tried the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629076/heroku-heroku-buildpack-registry-not-accessible-from-heroku-cli-plugin-buil][1]
(with mild changes, launched: `npm i @heroku/buildpack-registry valid-url` instead of the suggested solution) but it didn't work.

I've tried removing/reinstalling the package-lock.json, removed and reinstalled @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks several times and removed and reinstalled (with `npm i` ) my node_modules folder (and package.lock) several times, but the problem persists.

I tried reinstalling the dependancy that it asked for (valid-url or @heroku/buildpack-registry) to no effect.

I've also tried to deploy the app via the Command line (with `git push heroku master`) and deploying it through the Heroku web application, but these yield the same result.

I've narrowed it down to a buildpack issue, but not sure where to go next. I noticed Heroku supports a custom buildpacks repository (e.g. for create-react-app etc) but I'm worried that that will open up a whole new can of worms. Many thanks in advance for your assistance!

Here is my Package.json (and the error message is below. Please let me know if you require any more files or details)

```
{
  "name": "tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "heroku": "^7.50.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.5",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^3.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nMckenryan/rpgtracker.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nMckenryan/rpgtracker/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "/"
}
```

And here is the error message I keep seeing:

```
  $ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 19, done.
Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 125.39 KiB | 828.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.15.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.15.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! @heroku/buildpack-registry not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.M9Bs3/_logs/2021-03-09T15_25_49_297Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```